# I want to read a file which is in datapower through api gateway v10

Tags: api-gateway, ibm-datapower, apiconnect, apic

I'm using `url-open()` function but I'm getting an empty response.

Comment: Can you please provide some more specific information?

Comment: i have a file in datapower which contains server urls and i want to call that server url in my xslt node in api gateway v10

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  You don't need to do urlopen if you are running the code from the same appliance.

```
<!-- Load config file -->
<xsl:variable name="configFile" select="document('local:///myfolder/servers.xml')" />

<!-- Look in the XML file to find your server -->
<xsl:variable name="myURL">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$configFile/config/Servers/Server[@name='prod']/url" />
</xsl:variable>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <Servers>
        <Server name="prod">
            <url>www.google.com</url>
        </Server>
        <Server name="dev">
            <url>www.yahoo.com</url>
        </Server>
    </Servers>  
</config>
```